# mySQL - SUM and COUNT and JOIN to display all records

Tags: mysql

This is a following question to this one [Join two tables with SUM and COUNT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51500103/join-two-tables-with-sum-and-count). 
What I try to do is to have all values displayed as some are in history table and not in rota table or vice-versa (999 and 777)

So my tables are:

```
create table history (
    code int(10) primary key,
    PN varchar(10) not null,
    Qty int(10) not null,
    LOC_ID int(10));

insert into history values (1,  'T1', 1, 1);
insert into history values (2,  'A1', 2,2);
insert into history values (3,  'J1', 3,3);
insert into history values (4,  'A2', 1,4);
insert into history values (5,  'J2', 2,1);
insert into history values (6,  'A3', 3,2);
insert into history values (7,  'J3', 4,3);
insert into history values (8,  'T1', 5,4);
insert into history values (9,  'A1', 1,1);
insert into history values (10, '999', 3,2);
insert into history values (11, 'J2', 4,3);
insert into history values (12, 'A1', 3,4);
insert into history values (13, 'J2', 5,1);

create table rota (
        code int(10) primary key,
    PN varchar(10) not null,
    SN varchar(10) not null,
    LOC_ID int(10));

insert into rota values (1,     'T1',   't1a',1);
insert into rota values (2,     'A1',   'a1a',2);
insert into rota values (3,     'J1',   'j1a',3);
insert into rota values (4,     'A2',   'a2a',4);
insert into rota values (5,     'J2',   'j2a',1);
insert into rota values (6,     'A3',   'a3a',2);
insert into rota values (7,     'J3',   'j3a',3);
insert into rota values (8,     '777',   't1b',4);
insert into rota values (9,     'A1',   'a1b',1);
insert into rota values (10,    'J2',   'j2b',2);
insert into rota values (11,    'J2',   'j2c',3);
insert into rota values (12,    'A1',   'a1c',4);
insert into rota values (13,    'J2',   'j2d',1);
insert into rota values (14,    'J2',   'j2e',2);
insert into rota values (15,    'J2',   'j2f',3);

create table loca (
        code1 int(10) primary key,
    LOC varchar(10) not null);

insert into loca values (1,     'AAA');
insert into loca values (2,     'BBB');
insert into loca values (3,     'CCC');
insert into loca values (4,     'DDD');
```

The code I have got is

```
select CASE WHEN a.pn IS NULL THEN b.pn ELSE a.pn  END AS PN
, a.q
, b.c 
, a.LOC_ID
, b.LOC_ID

from
(select 
h.pn
, sum(qty) q
, h.LOC_ID
from 
history h

group by h.pn, h.LOC_ID) a
RIGHT JOIN 
(select 
r.pn
, count(sn) c
, r.LOC_ID
from 
rota r
group by r.pn, r.LOC_ID) b
on a.pn = b.pn WHERE a.LOC_ID = b.LOC_ID
order by a.pn;
```

The above code works great for all PN that are in both tables. The problem is for  values that are specific to one of the tables. I can remove the **WHERE** clause from JOIN but it is not corect. The question is - how to get all PNs from history and rota where some of them are present i just one table. I had some luck with RIGHT JOIN but that did not cover unique values from the other table. Any one came across solution before?

Results shoud look like the following table

```
 PN      LOC_ID     Count   Qty
 T1        1           1    1
 A1        2           1    2
 J1        3           1    3
 A2        4           1    1
 J2        1           2    2
 A3        2           1    3
 J3        3           1    4
777        4           1    NULL
 A1        1           1    1
 J2        2           2    NULL
 J2        3           2    4
 A1        4           1    3
 J2        1           2    2
 J2        2           2    NULL
 J2        3           2    4
999        2           NULL 3
```

Comment: update your question and add  your expected  result  too

Comment: Sounds suspiciously like `full outer join` (you want all records from both sides of the join), which is not supported by MySQL. But I agree with @scaisEdge , we need to see the expected results.

Comment: Results added. Please look at PN 777 and 999. If I can list them in my results the rest will follow :)

Comment: Why is table loca in the quesion but not in the query?

Comment: @P.Salmon - code was simplified. Any idea how to get desired results?

Comment: Yep, you want full outer join.

Comment: @Shadow - how to get it around in mysql?

Comment: I linked you the duplicate topic that explains how to simulate full outer join in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use another join and that is `left` and make them `union`

```
select t.PN,t.q,t.c,t.LOC_ID,t.LOC_ID_b from 
(
  select CASE WHEN a.pn IS NULL THEN b.pn ELSE a.pn  END AS PN
, a.q
, b.c 
, a.LOC_ID
, b.LOC_ID as LOC_ID_b

from
(select 
h.pn
, sum(qty) q
, h.LOC_ID
from 
history h

group by h.pn, h.LOC_ID) a
RIGHT JOIN 
(select 
r.pn
, count(sn) c
, r.LOC_ID
from 
rota r
group by r.pn, r.LOC_ID) b
on a.pn = b.pn and a.LOC_ID = b.LOC_ID

) as t
union 
select t2.PN,t2.q,t2.c,t2.LOC_ID,t2.LOC_ID_b from
(
  select CASE WHEN a.pn IS NULL THEN b.pn ELSE a.pn  END AS PN
, a.q
, b.c 
, a.LOC_ID
, b.LOC_ID as LOC_ID_b

from
(select 
h.pn
, sum(qty) q
, h.LOC_ID
from 
history h

group by h.pn, h.LOC_ID) a
left JOIN 
(select 
r.pn
, count(sn) c
, r.LOC_ID
from 
rota r
group by r.pn, r.LOC_ID
) b
on a.pn = b.pn and a.LOC_ID = b.LOC_ID
) t2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c20c81/20

Comment: Thanks Zaynul...777 and 999 are not present in the results.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c20c81/9 use this link here i all results returned as like your output

Comment: let me check again

Comment: check now it works

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c20c81/19

Comment: @ Zaynul - appreciate your help. Would you please have a look and see why 999 is not listed?

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c20c81/20

Comment: yes 999 also in listed

Comment: if you help it please accept my answer

Comment: @ Zaynul Bravo and well done :)

Comment: That's a big lump of code here's something simpler http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a717f5/1

Comment: @P.Salmon impressive! Would you be able to advise if the results can be presented in pivoted table. So each location will get one column for c and one for q? [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540057/mysql-5-5-pivot-values-to-columns-after-two-tables-linked-with-union